# Why I have an error performing password flow when I login?

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, asp.net-core, abp

When trying to login my browser generates an error saying "An error has occurred" and if I inspect it shows something like this:

[image: error]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's clear. The server responded with 400 status error: 400 Bad Request. Check your request.

Comment: I think my request is good... cause I tried in postman and it gives success.
Where can I check the request that is made?

Comment: You can check it in a network tab of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your Token Endpoint is configured to use a different Authentication Method. There is an error shown `invalid_client`, it looks like you're using password flow to authenticate but your token endpoint expects another grant type

Comment: Yes, I think that's it! What shall I do?

Comment: That depends on your access management solution which handles authentication. For example in keycloak you can configure your client profile to allow direct access grant.

Comment: I have a project in .net core which contains the web api and a project in angular which contains the frontend part. Which one shall I configure to allow direct access grant?

Comment: Check in .net core where your api call to /connect/token is handled. There must be the part which handles your password flow. But without knowing your exact backend implementation we won't be able to help you out on this

Answer (score 0):

That 400 error means that the server was unable to process the request sent by your application due to invalid syntax. Perhaps something invalid with your authentication token sent. Very hard to tell with so little information.

Comment: Tell me what you need to check that invalid syntax or problem that is occurring.

Comment: Authorization token in a login request? Why do you need to log in if you are authorized?